# How to apply the same class to multiple anchor tags (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have troubles inserting the same class into multiple anchor tags. This is what I have now which works perfectly.

HTML

```
<nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-link">
    <a href="#home">
        <img src="somelogoihave" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <a  href="#product">Product details</a>
    <a  href="#prices">Pricing</a>
    <a  href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav-link{
overflow: hidden;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 130px;}

.nav-link a{
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;}

.nav-link a:hover{
background: grey;
color: black;}
```

However, I am doing an assignment that requires me to assign class="nav-link" into each  tag.
E.g: <a class='nav-link...>.

Can anyone help me with this? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What problems are you encountering?

Comment: @Spectric I did not know how to reformat my CSS to allow my anchor tags to each have the same class within their respective tags (<a class='nav-link...>).  Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the trouble? It sounds like you know what to do:

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
    <a href="#home">
        <img src="somelogoihave" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#product">Product details</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#prices">Pricing</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
</nav>
```

Then adapt the CSS to match:

```css
#nav-bar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 130px;
}

a.nav-link {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a.nav-link:hover {
background: grey;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: Hello @AbsentBird! thank you so much you fixed my problem! The issue was I did not know how to tweak the CSS to adapt to my new html code which required a class for each anchor tag.